# Python: Len() function return wrong value

Tags: python, regex

Somehow, the below code using LEN() function return all value 1.
The code return $120.35 for the first line and len() should be more than 1.
Can you please tell me what is going on with it?
Thank you,
HHC

```
data8=("value: $120.35 ","value: sdsds","value: $99.35 :","error: 3232")
for line in data8:
    dollar = re.findall('\$\S+',line)
    print(dollar , '---len:' ,len(dollar))
```

Comment: Pretty sure that'll cause an error in the assignment of that tuple to data8, since you've got two strings without a comma between them.

Comment: Why don't you just print `dollar` and see what it is?  Or try using a debugger.

Comment: I don’t do much python so this may be wrong, but findall appears to return a list containing the matches so your len call is just getting the number of items within it?

Comment: What do you expect as the result of your `len(dollar)` exactly?

Comment: Running your exact code, I get 3 lines, all correct, the first and last giving a len of 1, and the second giving a len of 0. Which is what I would expect. `"value: $120.35 "` has exactly 1 `$` in it, the len should not be more than 1.

Answer (score 1):

Is this more what you're aiming for?

```
import re
data8 = ("value: $120.35 ", "value: sdsds", "value: $99.35 :""error: 3232")
for line in data8:
    dollars = re.findall("\$\S+", line)
    for dollar in dollars or ():
        print(dollar, "---len:", len(dollar))
```